What is the point of a class with an interface implementing a method that is then forced to be overridden?
The documentation gives as an example a class with an interface, which has a method already implemented instead of being abstract.
The class that wants to implement the interface is forced to implement the function, which will always override the original function.
So, in what scenarios is it useful for the class marked with an interface to already implement a function?
interface class Vehicle {
  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}

class MockVehicle implements Vehicle {
  @override
  void moveForward(int meters) {
    // ...
  }
}


you're forced to override only if you want to create your own implementation of that interface, but you don't have to do so usually, you can use original class as is if you need default behavior

I don't know Dart but I'd be surprised if it were true that "the class that wants to implement the interface is forced to implement the function [that has a base implementation in the interface]".

@jarmod dart tries to avoid fragile base class problem so if you want to implement interface - you must implement all methods, but you can also extend interface class (if they are in the same library and thus you can reuse base implementation)

From the documentation:

Libraries outside of the interface's own defining library can implement the interface, but not extend it.

Which implies that within the defining library it is possible to extend a class marked with the interface modifier and make use of a concrete method defined in a super class.
